# How to filter with "contains"?

Tags: python, regex, django

I try to filter and get some set of objects using this segment.

```
baseSet = ThreadedComment.objects.filter(tree_path__contains = baseT.comment_ptr_id)
```

but it brings some objects that are not supposed to be there. 
For example, my baseT.comment_ptr_id is 1, it brought items with these tree_path.

```
comment_ptr_id=1 treepath = 0000000001
comment_ptr_id=3 treepath = 0000000001/0000000003
comment_ptr_id=4 treepath = 0000000001/0000000003/0000000004
comment_ptr_id=8 treepath = 0000000001/0000000003/0000000004/0000000008
comment_ptr_id=10 treepath = 0000000006/0000000010
comment_ptr_id=11 treepath = 0000000011
```

The last 2 ones are not supposed to be here. But since their tree_path contains "1"
filter brings those as well.

How can I write regex to create a filter that does not bring those items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do

```
baseSet = ThreadedComment.objects.filter(tree_path__contains = ('%010i' % int(baseT.comment_ptr_id)))
```

so that the search string for id=1 will be "0000000001" and won't be a substring of "0000000011"?

**EDIT:** As per the comment below, it might be better to use COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS. This is a little messier because you're using formatting to set a formatting tag. It looks like this:

```
tree_path__contains = ('%%0%ii' % COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS % int(baseT.comment_ptr_id))
```

Comment: `COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS = len('0000000000') - len(str(baseT.comment_ptr_id))` right? if so why not: `'0' * COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS + str(baseT.comment_ptr_id)` I don't see why you have to mess with the template.

Comment: Well I think the point is to use COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS instead of len(<string of 0's>), or else there's no gain in flexibility over the original. With that said, yes, you could do ('0' * (COMMENT_PATH_DIGITS - len(str(baseT.comment_ptr_id)))) + str(baseT.comment_ptr_id) but IMHO that's messier.

Answer (score 2):

the regexp would be `'(^|/)0*%d(/|$)' % baseT.comment_ptr_id` and you use it with [tree_path__regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#regex)

read about MPTT for alternatives to this approach.